# Reading lines from file in Scala

Tags: scala, io

Again Scala basic operations are making my life painful :D.
So I have to read lines from file...just a trivial I/O operation.

In every example on internet they are doing:

```
import scala.io.Source

for(line <- Source.fromPath("integerArray.txt").getLines())
      println(line)
```

But my IntelliJ is throwing error : value fromPath is not a member of object scala.io.Source.

Does anyone knows what is problem here? ... I have installed last version of Scala few months ago and IntelliJ Scala plugin is also up to date so I doubt this might be a reason...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `fromPath` in `Source`, just a `fromFile`, which accepts a String path. Good luck on Coursera.

Comment: omg. I have c/p first example and there was fromPath but now I see other examples had fromFile...maybe I should be little more patient with scala :D ... haha..thanks, right now I am spending more time on learning scala than algorithms (that happens when you want to do 2 things at the same time) ...

Answer (score 4):

There was `Source.fromPath` around 2.8.  Briefly.

What, you're not using [this version](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/2c31c03c6247d0adf5a9a83a8d779c9631b6c10c#src/library/scala/io/Source.scala)?

It was removed [here, with "Review by community."](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e9d3987da750e2d6ce154dd3b2ceca309b665674#src/library/scala/io/Source.scala)

See? We just weren't paying attention.